# Cannot pass an 2D array in C++ which gives error cannot convert int(*) to int*

Tags: c++, arrays

The code is

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void lookup(int* main,int row,int col,int num,int* up)
{
int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<num;j++)
        {
        if((row==i && (col==j+1 || col==j-1)) || (col=j && (row==i+1 || row==i-1)))//neighbour condition
        {
        if((*(main+i*num)+j)==1)
        {
            if((*(up+(i*num)+j)==1))
            {
                 *((up+num*i)+j)=1;
                 lookup(main,i,j,num,up);
            }
        }
        }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
// flipping array b, input array a, we have marked array b
int n,i,j,botr,botc,place;
cin>>n;
int a[n][n],b[n][n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cin>>a[i][j];
        b[i][j]=0;
    }
}
cin>>botr>>botc;
b[botr][botc]=1;
lookup(a,botr,botc,n,b);
//seeing which are 1 in b
place=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
if(b[i][j]==1)
place++;
}
}
cout<<place;
}
```

and the error I get is

```
cannot convert 'int (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)n) + -1)) + 1)]' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void lookup(int*, int, int, int, int*)'|
```

So I am given a matrix with index starting from 0,0. The matrix is of values 0 and 1. Now when I am given any particular position(with the value 1 in that position) I have to find the all possible distinct points where I can go and the value is 1, given I can only move in adjacent ways and the ways does not contain 0.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, there error is just what is says. You can't convert a pointer to a variable length array to a pointer to int, they are different things. And, on top of it, variable length arrays are not part of C++ and it is a compiler extension that you are able to compile the code.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk, Re "*You can't convert a pointer to a variable length array to a pointer to int*", Yes you can. That's not what the error says.

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` is not an array of integers, but rather an array of an array of integers. Hence, it does not convert to a pointer to an integer.

From what I understand of your code, you can use `&a[0]`, as `a[0]` *is* an array of integers.

Comment: I think you meant *"you can use a[0]"*. `&a[0]` gives the same error. And while this will work as intended with reasonable compilers, accessing beyond the first column through this pointer is technically probably UB. (But then again VLA are not even standard C++, so who knows.)

Answer (score -1):

So Thanks for the reply, but I couldn't implement your method. Anyway here is the workaround I figured. So I defined two extra variables `L1` and `L2` of type `int*`. Defined `L1=a[0][0], L2=b[0][0]`. Then passed them in the `lookup()` function and worked like a charm. I will always pass 2d or more dimensional array this way from now on. Thanks for help guys.

Comment: No, that should not work, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/V7Q-ue). The answer by @AmiTavory is going the correct direction, except for what I mentioned in the comment to their answer. If the answer didn't work for you, you could have commented on it.

Comment: actually it did work, as I passed the initial address properly. Why it should not work explain.

Comment: `a[0][0]` has type `int`, but `L1` has type `int*`. You cannot assign `int` to `int*`. What compiler are you using? Did you give it a `-fpermissive` flag or something similar? If so, you should not do that.